Vonage continuous voice API conversation issue
Building a Vonage integration with a local backend app.
The user should call the Vonage phone number, then hear the opening line The user speech should be recorded, parsed by our app, which returns an audio response. The response should be streamed or played back to the user, and the process should repeat until the user hangs up.
All of the code executes properly, but no matter what ncco I place in the handle_recording endpoint, it doesn't execute. All of the code around it does, but the NCCO itself doesn't. I've tried building it using one NCCO, I tried websockets, tried client methods instead of returning NCCO's. Nothing seems to work, and I'm lost in the Vonage docs (which are largely outdated and scattered).
Here is the code:
from fastapi import APIRouter, Request, BackgroundTasks, HTTPException
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
import base64
import os
import vonage
import httpx
import asyncio

router = APIRouter()

async def cleanup_temp_file(file_path: str):
    try:
        os.remove(file_path)
        print(f"Temporary file {file_path} deleted.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error deleting temporary file {file_path}: {e}")

@router.post("/webhooks/answer")
@router.get("/webhooks/answer")
async def answer_call(request: Request):
    ncco = [
        {
            "action": "talk",
            "text": "Hello, please start speaking.",
            "endOnSilence": 3  # End on 3 seconds of silence
        },
        {
            "action": "record",
            "eventUrl": [f"{request.url.scheme}://{request.url.hostname}/webhooks/record"],
            "endOnSilence": 3,  # End on 3 seconds of silence
            "endOnKey": "#"
        }
    ]
    return JSONResponse(content=ncco)

@router.post("/webhooks/record")
async def handle_recording_post(request: Request, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    data = await request.json()
    print(f"POST request received at /webhooks/record with data: {data}")

    recording_url = data.get("recording_url")
    conversation_uuid = data.get("conversation_uuid")

    if not recording_url or not conversation_uuid:
        return JSONResponse(status_code=400, content={"message": "Recording URL or conversation UUID missing"})

    client = vonage.Client(
        key=os.getenv("VONAGE_API_KEY"),
        secret=os.getenv("VONAGE_API_SECRET"),
        application_id=os.getenv("VONAGE_APPLICATION_ID"),
        private_key="./private.key"
    )

    recording = client.voice.get_recording(recording_url)
    audio_base64 = base64.b64encode(recording).decode('utf-8')

    payload = {
        "user": "vonage_user",
        "text": audio_base64
    }

    audio_to_audio_endpoint = os.getenv("AUDIO_TO_AUDIO_ENDPOINT")
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-API-Key': "123_3_1"
    }

    async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=30.0) as client:  # Increased timeout
        retries = 3
        for attempt in range(retries):
            try:
                response = await client.post(audio_to_audio_endpoint, json=payload, headers=headers)
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    break
            except httpx.RequestError as e:
                print(f"Attempt {attempt + 1} failed with error: {e}")
                await asyncio.sleep(2)  # Wait before retrying
        else:
            return JSONResponse(status_code=500, content={"message": "Failed to process audio after retries"})


    if response.status_code != 200:
        return JSONResponse(status_code=500,
                            content={"message": f"Failed to process audio with response: {response.text}"})

    bot_audio_base64 = response.json()[1].get("audio")
    bot_audio_content = base64.b64decode(bot_audio_base64)

    # Save the audio file to a static directory to be served
    static_dir = "./static"
    os.makedirs(static_dir, exist_ok=True)
    audio_file_path = os.path.join(static_dir, f"{conversation_uuid}.mp3")
    with open(audio_file_path, "wb") as audio_file:
        audio_file.write(bot_audio_content)

    # Add a background task to clean up the temporary file after streaming
    background_tasks.add_task(cleanup_temp_file, audio_file_path)

    ncco = [
        {
            "action": "stream",
            "streamUrl": [f"{request.url.scheme}://{request.url.hostname}/static/{os.path.basename(audio_file_path)}"],
            "loop": 1,  # Ensuring the audio streams continuously
        },
        {
            "action": "record",
            "eventUrl": [f"{request.url.scheme}://{request.url.hostname}/webhooks/record"],
            "endOnSilence": 3,  # End on 3 seconds of silence
            "endOnKey": "#"
        }
    ]

    # Log NCCO for debugging
    print(f"Returning NCCO: {ncco}")
    return JSONResponse(content=ncco)

@router.get("/webhooks/record")
async def handle_recording_get(request: Request):
    data = request.query_params
    print(f"GET request received at /webhooks/record with query params: {data}")

    # Handle different statuses or actions as needed, for now we just return 200 OK
    return JSONResponse(status_code=200, content={"message": "GET request received and handled"})

Tried doing a simple NCCO request with talk action only, using the streaming and update methods of the client class, and going through a websocket.
